# Is it possible to detect self signed certificates with Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

How can I differentiate valid SSL certificate and self signed ones with Wireshark? Are there any key differences which can be seen on traffic capture easily?

Answer (score 3):

JFYI Self-signed doesn't mean invalid and vice versa. You seem to be interested in quick discovery of self-signed sertificates, so here it is:

Server sends certificate chain during TLS handhsake (more details in [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)). It's sent in binary format (most often it's [x509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)), but it's unencrypted, so wireshark parses certificates and shows their data in packet details. So inspect all certificates provided by server in "Certificate" TLS message during TLS handshake and ensure non of them has identical data in subject and issuer fields, otherwise it's self-signed cert.

For example, you can train on [this capture](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=11612) from [wireshark samples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures). Here is what I see in quite outdated Wireshark 1.12.9:
[image: self-signed certificate discovered]